# How could I use Eisenstein's Criterion to determine irreducibility of $x^{12} + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

It seems reducible if I follow the criterion directly, but I know this is not so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eisenstein criterion needs, that $p|1$ in this case and $p^2|1$. But there is no p that divides 1 in the first place. So it does not work.

Comment: Eisenstein is a *sufficient* condition for irreducibility, not a necessary one. Just because you can't use it to prove this is irreducible does not mean it is not irreducible. (Although as someone just answered, it does happen to be reducible.)

Comment: Also, Eisenstein might not apply directly, but possibly only after a transformation (like $x\mapsto x+a$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^{12}+1=(x^4+1)(x^8-x^4+1)$

Therefore not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$